# In the Dead Sea Scrolls, for Genesis Chapter 18, do we have no more than 5 or 6 verses?

Tags: genesis, dead-sea-scrolls

In the Dead Sea Scrolls, for Genesis Chapter 18, do we have no more than 5 or 6 verses?

i notice this link only lists 5/6 verses, i'm wondering if that website is complete. Or if there is more we have from Gen 18?

I'm really interested in if we have the whole of Gen 18 in the DSS

http://dssenglishbible.com/genesis%2018.htm

> Genesis 18 from Scroll 8Q1 Genesis
>
> 20 Yahweh said, “Because the cry of Sodom and Gomorrah is great, and
>   because their sin is very grievous, 21 I will go down now, and see
>   whether their deeds are as bad as the reports which have come to me.
>   If not, I will know.”
>
> 22 The men turned from there, and went toward Sodom, but Abraham stood
>   yet before Yahweh.
>
> [..]
>
> 24 What if there are fifty righteous within the city? Will you consume
>   and not spare the place for the fifty righteous who are in it? 25 Be
>   it far from you to do things like that, to kill the righteous with the
>   wicked, so that the righteous should be like the wicked. May that be
>   far from you. Shouldn’t the Judge of all the earth do right?”

**added**

What i'm asking is, are there other scrolls that haven't yet been digitized or translated, that might have other verses of chapter 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text translated here is from a single scroll, namely 8Q1.  It may have been complete originally but is now, by admission of the web site itself, "fragmentary".  Note the index to this document - whole chapters are missing and what is there is occasionally illegible.

I have not seen this scroll personally but have seen several others.  Most DSS are indeed fragmentary because they are so poorly preserved - rotted away with time - we are lucky to have at least some left to confirm that text of the Bible.

Therefore, I assume that more of the text was originally part of this fragmentary scroll but the text that is displayed is all that remains.

There is a complete list of Dead Sea Scrolls here >> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_Dead_Sea_Scrolls

According to this source, none has a complete Gen 18.

Comment: I'm aware of the nature of the situation. See my additional note to my question that elaborate on what I'm asking

Comment: See extra material added to answer.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_Dead_Sea_Scrolls

Comment: thanks, your last line answers the question